# Jasper Reports 5 para 6 Métodos obsoletos

Tags: java, relatório, jasper-reports

Criei alguns relátorios atraves do `TIBCO Jaspersoft® Studio - Visual Designer for JasperReports` e estou utilizando a lib abaixo no meu projeto.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Nas versões anteriores estava utilizando `JRXlsExporter` mas alguns métodos estão obsoletos e não encontrei a nova forma na documentação oficial (ou eu não soube procurar ou realmente não foi atualizado).

Exemplo:

```
   JRXlsExporter exporter  = new JRXlsExporter(); 
   response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;    filename=PONTOS_DE_VENDA.xls");
   response.setContentType("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel"); //DEPRECATED
   exporter.setParameter(JExcelApiExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint); //DEPRECATED
   exporter.setParameter(JExcelApiExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM,  response.getOutputStream()); //DEPRECATED
```

Alguém já usou essa nova versão? Ou onde encontro algum exemplo de utilização.

Comment: amigo, depreciado?  não seria obsoletos?

Comment: @PabloVargas apesar de você provavelmente estar com a razão quanto ao fato de que a tradução de "deprecated" não estar da melhor forma possível, o termo "depreciado" acabou sendo adotado pela cultura brasileira (não sei dizer de Portugal). Como você pode ver por exemplo nesse link: http://www.devmedia.com.br/tags-e-atributos-depreciados-na-html/28042, onde os termos "obsoletos" e "depreciados" são usados de forma intercambiável. Portanto, eu diria que não há um consenso quanto ao termo correto. Já vi até mesmo a palavra "aposentado" sendo usada para tal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

De acordo com o Javadoc da classe [JRXlsExporter](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/export/JRXlsExporter.html):

**`setParameter`** -> *Substituído por `setExporterInput(ExporterInput)`, `setConfiguration(ExporterConfiguration)`, `setConfiguration(ReportExportConfiguration)` e `setExporterOutput(ExporterOutput)`*.

Não sei de que tipo é seu objeto `response` (se for `ServletResponse` o método [`setContentType`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#setContentType(java.lang.String)) não parece ter sido descontinuado).

---

**Mais informações**: [SOen - JasperReports 5.6: JRXlsExporter.setParameter is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24117878/jasperreports-5-6-jrxlsexporter-setparameter-is-deprecated)

Comment: Foi justamente isso que estava procurando vou postar aqui o código de como ficou. Vlw pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

No final cheguei a este código, com a resposta do **Anthony Accioly** logo acima:

```
        JRXlsExporter exporter  = new JRXlsExporter(); 
        SimpleXlsReportConfiguration configuration = new SimpleXlsReportConfiguration();
        configuration.setOnePagePerSheet(false);
        ......
        exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
        exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(response.getOutputStream()));
        exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);
        exporter.exportReport();
```

Neste caso tive que trocar os `exporter.setParameter` pelo `SimpleXlsReportConfiguration` que posso montar a mesma configuração que usei no exporter. Visualmente ficou até mais elegante.